# return passed array keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, return

I am working in WordPress. I am using a plugin to get the admin options. The plugin takes an argument as an ID to get the value from the database like so.

```
 $option = ot_get_option('email_address');
```

The above line of code would return

```
 myEmail@example.com
```

I want to write a helper function that would get multiple values at once. Normally, I would get the options like this.

```
 $option_1 = ot_get_option('option1');
 $option_2 = ot_get_option('option2');
 $option_3 = ot_get_option('option3');
```

I figured there could be a better way that would look a little nicer. I put together this little function that does work

```
 function ritual_get_options($arg_list = array())
 {

   $options = array();
   foreach( $arg_list as $key => $value){
     $options[] = ot_get_option($value, array());
   }
   return $options;
}
```

using the function above, I can now pass the id's of the options like so

```
 ritual_get_options('option1','option2','option3');
```

My issue is that the above will return an array with numeric keys. 0,1,2. Here is the exact array that is getting returned when I do a var_dump on the front end

```
   [0]=>
   string(16) "100 Main Street,"
   [1]=>
   string(18) "Hamilton, Ontario."
   [2]=>
   string(15) "+1 800 999 9898"
   [3]=>
   string(19) "mail@yourdomain.com"
```

I want to return the array keys with the value so that I can easily figure out what value is in what key. Here is the line that I used to get the above array

```
 $options = ritual_get_options(array('number' => 'streetnumber','street' => 'street','phone' => 'phone_number','email' => 'email'));
```

When I go to use the returned values, I want to be able to use the key so that I could do

```
 echo $options['number'];
```

instead of doing

```
 echo $options[0];
```

I have not been able to figure out how to return the keys passed in to the function and preserve them into through the return.

Answer (score 0):

Set the option name as key while building the array:

```
foreach( $arg_list as $option ){
    $options[$option] = ot_get_option( $option );
}
```

Btw, using [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) on the `$options` array will allow you to use e.g. `$phone_number` instead of `$options['phone_number']`

Comment: I tried that and got the same array back. It didn't change anything.  `function ritual_get_options($arg_list = array())
{
    //$arg_list = func_get_args();
 
 $options = array();
 foreach( $arg_list as $option){
  $options[$option] = ot_get_option($option, array());
 }
 return $options;
}`